# Replace phone numbers with asterisks pattern by Regex

Tags: android, regex

I want to apply a mask to my phone numbers replacing some characters with "*".

The specification is the next:

Phone entry: `+(123) 123-12345`

Output: `+(123) 12*-***45`

Phone entry: `+(123) 123 12 12345`

Output: `+(123) 12* ** ***45`

I was trying with this pattern: `(?<!\()\d(?!\d?$)` and the replacing the matches with a "*"

But the final input is something like `+(123) 123-12345` -> `+(1**) ***-***45`

Comment: What is the actual replacement logic or rules?

Comment: Try `replaceAll("(?<=[\\d-])\\d(?=\\d{2}|-)", "*")`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pwe9sk/1).

Comment: Try the https://ideone.com/gi4JI3 solution.

Comment: To me the requirements are a bit unclear. 1.) Are you masking these in some text or is this phone number the only input to process? 2.) What's the specification? Mask every digit with `*` that's not in parentheses and has at least two adjacent digits somewhere before and two after it?

Comment: I had played with [this demo (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/NO4lFR/1), leaving it as a comment if it's of help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java you can use a finite quantifier in a lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<=\)\h\d\d[\d\h-]{0,100})\d(?=[\h\d-]*\d\d$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\)` Assert `)` to the lelft

  - `\h\d\d` Match a space and 2 digits
  - `[\d\h-]{0,100}` Match 0-100 (100 is arbitrary but finite) digits, spaces or `-`
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `\d` Match a single digit (that will be replaced with `*`)
- `(?=[\h\d-]*\d\d$)` Positive lookahead, assert optional digits, spaces or `-` to the right followed by 2 digits at the end of the string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/892zqb/1) and a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/blp4P9).

In the replacement use a single asterix `*`

Example using Java

```
String regex = "(?<=\\) \\d\\d[\\d\\h-]{0,100})\\d(?=[\\h\\d-]*\\d\\d$)";
String string = "+(123) 123-12345\n"
```

- "+(123) 123 12 12345";

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
  String result = matcher.replaceAll("*");

  System.out.println(result);

Output

```
+(123) 12*-***45
+(123) 12* ** ***45
```